# Replace string in text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file at some location on the server. This file contains a string value and a timestamp.
I want to replace this specific line with the latest timestamp using PowerShell.

Below is the notepad file's data:

```
Test Service|05-09-2017 01-09-41
```

Here 05-09-2017 01-09-41 is MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss and I want to replace this line with the latest timestamp.

So, if after two minutes it should be

```
Test Service|05-09-2017 01-11-41
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
$ReplaceString = "$ServiceName + "|" + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss')"
Get-Content Path -Replace($ServiceName + "|" + $StringLastRunTime,$ReplaceString) | Set-Content Path
```

But it does not generate expected output.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not being so clear with requirements

I want to monitor critical services installed on the server using PowerShell script. I have listed all the services to be monitored in one text file and that path has been mentioned in the script. This script will execute every 5 minutes and if service is not installed or service is stopped it will generate an email notification. To prevent email flood I am thinking of updating a timestamp with the service name in the text file.
So, if I find one service in stopped mode or not installed, I will send a notification and will update the timestamp of when last it was sent. I have a resend interval which will check every five minutes and if that interval is passed, I have to again send the notification and I want to update the timestamp.

Code (*I have removed email sending portion to make it less complex*):

```
$ServicesList = Get-Content E:\ServiceReports\Services.txt
$ResendEmailInterval = 10 #In Minutes

foreach ($Service in $ServicesList) {
    $ServiceName = $Service
    $Service = Get-Service -Display $Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $serviceDisplayName = $Service.displayname
    if (-Not $Service) {
        #Service is not installed. So need to send an email alert and update the timestamp.
        Write-Host $ServiceName.IndexOf("|")
        if ($ServiceName.IndexOf("|") -gt 0) {
            $ServiceName,$StringLastRunTime = $ServiceName.Split('|')
            $LastRunTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($StringLastRunTime, "MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss", $null)
            Write-Host $ServiceName
            Write-Host $LastRunTime
            Write-Host (Get-Date).AddMinutes($ResendEmailInterval)
            if ($LastRunTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes($ResendEmailInterval)) {
                Write-Host "time to run"
                $ReplaceString = $ServiceName + "|" + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss')
                Write-Host $ServiceName"|"$StringLastRunTime
                Write-Host $ReplaceString
                #$ServiceName = "Test Service";
                $ReplaceString = "{0}|{1}" -f $ServiceName, (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss');
                (Get-Content -Path $ServicesListPath) -replace ('([^|]+).*', $ReplaceString) | Set-Content $ServicesListPath;
                $ServicesList -replace ($ServiceName + "|" + $StringLastRunTime, $ReplaceString) | Set-Content $ServicesListPath
            }
        } else {
            $ReplaceString = $ServiceName + "|" + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss')
            $ServicesList -replace ($ServiceName, $ReplaceString) | Set-Content $ServicesListPath
            $i = $i+1;
        }
    } else {
        if ($Service.Status -eq "Stopped") {
            Write-Host "Service is stopped"
            #Time to send email and update the time stamp
            $i = $i+1;
        } else {
            #Write-Host "Service is running. Nothing to do."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual output that is generated by this?

Comment: Can you paste the whole script?

Comment: @30000MONKEYS updated

Comment: I say use CSV with type information, this way you'll be able to `Import-CSV` and get your info parsed into respective types right away. No regex, no extra hassle.

Answer (score 9):

You could do this using a *regex*:

```
$filePath = 'yourPath'
(Get-Content $filePath -raw) -replace '([^|]+).*', ('$1|{0:MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss}' -f (Get-Date)) |
    Set-Content $filePath
```

[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/maml7w/1):

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain me the regex part

Comment: @RanadipDutta Check the link I added to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to monitor critical services installed on the server using PowerShell script.

Since this seems to be your motivation to do all this scripting, I'm going to tell you a better way to monitor services than writing timestamps into a file:

- Open **View local services** from the start menu.
- Open the properties window for a service you want to monitor
- On the **Recovery** tab, set up the options for first, second and subsequent failures to your liking. You can choose to restart a failing service and even run a program. You can run a PowerShell script like this: enter `PowerShell` as the program and `c:\path\to\your\script.ps1` as the parameter.
- In that script you can then simply check which of the important services is not running at the moment.

Comment: While this is straightforward and a better solution to monitor services than the OP's one, it does not answer the question.

Comment: Strictly answering the question is a disservice to OP if this is a better way to achieve his goal of `I want to monitor critical services`.

Comment: Sure, just saying. I personally agree with you and like your answer, but as I know, others see this different.

Answer (score 3):

Since your file is used as a database, you should instead use a CSV-based storage.

First, because you have cmdlets designed to parse CSV files to and from, namely `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`. Second, because with CSV you are able to save type information for columns.

This way you can generate the proper CSV once, then run `Import-Csv` resulting in an array of `PSObject`s, then you process each of them updating the timestamp with `(Get-Date)` or `[DateTime]::Now`, then you plain `Export-Csv` overwriting saved data, with a possible save as backup together with working copy. Like this:

```
$ServicesList = Import-Csv E:\ServiceReports\Services.txt -encoding UTF8
foreach ($service in $serviceslist) {
    # A PSObject is expected to have "Service" and "Timestamp" fields
    $servicename = $service.service
    $ts = $service.timestamp
    if ($ts -eq "") { $ts=get-date "01.01.2000 00:00:00" }
    $sysservice = Get-Service -displayname $servicename -ea silentlycontinue
    if (-not $sysservice) {
        if ($ts -lt [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1*$ResendEmailInterval)) {
            # Send email - no service
            $service.timestamp = [DateTime]::Now # Just that
        }
    } elseif ($sysservice.status -eq 'Stopped') {
        Write-Host "Service $servicename is stopped"
        if ($ts -lt [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1*$ResendEmailInterval)) {
            # Send email - service stopped
            $service.timestamp=[DateTime]::Now # Update timestamp
        }
    } else {
        # Service is running, set timestamp to "zero"
        $service.timestamp = Get-Date "01.01.2000 00:00:00"
    }
}
$ServicesList | Export-Csv E:\ServiceReports\Services.txt -encoding UTF8
```

Prior to this, fill the file with the following content, providing actual names for services you're targetting to monitor:

```
"Service","Timestamp"
"First service",""
"Second service",""
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your supplied code and without knowing what the actual output is, I'd expect your `$ReplaceString` to be wrong. Your quotes don't add up. This should work for it:

```
$ReplaceString = $ServiceName + "|" + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you added to the description seems not to work. Furthermore, I suggest using [the format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) (`-f`) for strings.

```
$ServiceName = "Test Service";
$ReplaceString = "{0}|{1}" -f $ServiceName, (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss');
(Get-Content -Path $Path) -replace ('([^|]+).*', $ReplaceString) | Set-Content $Path;
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more description,code and use case

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your example...

```
$ReplaceString = "$ServiceName + "|" + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss')"
Get-Content Path -Replace($ServiceName + "|" + $StringLastRunTime,$ReplaceString) | Set-Content Path
```

Could probably be fixed.

1. The string you are searching for with `-replace` needs to be a regex. The `|` character is special in a regex and needs to be escaped. I'd compose the regex on a separate line and store it in a variable named $regex so I wouldn't forget.
2. You want to run the replacement on every line coming out of Get-Content, so it needs to be done in a separate pipeline step, using `%` (short for "foreach-object").
3. I'd use string interpolation to form the strings. That's optional, but I'll show you what I mean...
4. I presume `Path` should be a variable, not the literal name of the file.
5. Getting and setting the content of the same file in a single pipeline is likely to result in a conflict. Doing it on two different lines is easiest.

A fixed version might look something like this:

```
$regex = "^$([regex]::Escape($serviceName))\|.*"
$ReplaceString = "${ServiceName}|$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))"
$result = Get-Content $Path | %{ $_ -replace($regex,$ReplaceString)}
Set-Content $Path -Value $result
```

P.S.: The [regex]::Escape part is just in case ServiceName has special characters in it...

Also, this script doesn't keep the file locked during the period between when the last two lines execute, so some other application *might* update it in between. With text files, the last writer wins, so in case of a collision, some updates might be lost.